# Building a basic interactive map with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, interactive

I am creating an interactive map in jQuery, and am using a custom hand-drawn map. I have a series of "trigger points" placed throughout the map, absolutely positioned, relative to the size of the map. WHen a use hovers over these trigger points, a tooltip is displayed with information about the location.

HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="map" style="position:relative; background: url(images/map.jpg">
    <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationA" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:3px"><h1 class="tooltip">Location A Title</h1></div>
    <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationB" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:24px"><h1 class="tooltip">Location B Title</h1></div>
    <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationC" style="position:absolute; left:140px; top:35px"><h1 class="tooltip">Location C Title</h1></div>
    <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationD" style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:103px"><h1 class="tooltip">Location D Title</h1></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".trigger").hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".tooltip").fadeIn();
}, function(){
   $(this).find(".tooltip").fadeOut();
});
```

A few Questions:
1) Is this the best way to go about a basic interactive map with JQuery?
2) I want to have a list of locations off to the right. When a user clicks on the link it should ALSO trigger the tooltip for that pertaining link. As shown above, there is a data-loc attribute in each trigger-point. If I set the same data-points in the anchor links to the right, how would I use jQuery to link them up and trigger the fading in and out of the pertaining tooltip?

Comment: btw, .tooltip is hidden by default

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do 2 with a standard tooltip, unless you want to go down the horrible road of programatically creating mouse events. I think you'll have to create your own similar floating divs. This may be a better idea anyway, as tooltips are useless for touch screen users, and you could also trigger them on touch.

Comment: Im not sure I understand Robert... what do you mean create similar floating divs? I want an external list of links to work with the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't a *best* way to do this.  One slightly more descriptive way is to [use the area tag](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/667ddf/working-with-area-tag-in-html5/) instead of a div.

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<body>
  <img src="image/all balls.jpg" style="width: 450px; height: 450px;" 
       alt="Balls" usemap="#BallMap" />
  <map name="BallMap">
    <area id="whiteArea" class="hoverArea" shape="circle" coords="78,81,76.5" 
          nohref="nohref" alt="white" />
    <area id="blueArea" class="hoverArea" shape="circle" coords="260,81,76.5" 
          nohref="nohref" alt="blue" />
    <area id="redArea" class="hoverArea" shape="circle" coords="84,254,76.5"
          nohref="nohref" alt="red" />
  </map>
</body>
</html>
```

Then similarly:

```
$(".hoverArea").hover(function(){
   showToolTip($(this));
}, function(){
   hideToolTip($(this));
});
```

Probably a little more work to write the custom functions for showing a tooltip.  (note: I've never used Area myself. )

**Update**

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.

A semi-hacky way, since you are already using absolutes is to put another div around the current div's but have them absolutely positioned way to the right.  Hacky but works.

I wouldn't do that, cause this would be way better in my opinion:

```
<div id="map" style="position:relative; background: url(images/map.jpg">
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationA" id="locationA"
       style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:3px">
    <h1 class="tooltip">Location A Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationB" id="locationB" 
       style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:24px">
    <h1 class="tooltip">Location B Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationC" id="locationC"
       style="position:absolute; left:140px; top:35px">
    <h1 class="tooltip">Location C Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationD" id="locationD"
       style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:103px">
    <h1 class="tooltip">Location D Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationA"> Loc A
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationB"> Loc B
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationC"> Loc C
  </div>
  <div class="trigger" data-loc="locationD"> Loc D
  </div>
<div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$(".trigger").hover(function(){
   $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").fadeIn();
}, function(){
   $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This is helpful, I was considering using areas...but can you offer an idea/ solution to part 2 of my question?

Comment: Although I think I prefer positioning vs image maps still

Comment: THanks! In the sidebar, I want every link to be visible at any time, and they should be anchor links, versus divs. When a user clicks on   a sidebar link, it should fade in the tooltip of its pertaining div.trigger (with matching data attr). That make sense?

Comment: Ok... so use my example and change `div` to `a` and add the appropriate attributes you need.

Comment: well, we would need another click event for the links...my question is how to fadeIn the tooltip based on matching data attr. Something like this (in pseudo):  $("a").click(function(){  find div.trigger with same data attr and fade in its children with class of tooltip  });

Comment: In my example you don't two triggers; the div over the map, and the item off to the right. They use the same class to trigger the event.  When the event happens, it uses the `data-loc` value to find a .tooltip in the specified ID.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that if I click on a sidebar link (or div) it will trigger the tooltip to fadeIn, even without the hover of .hoverarea?